# Get specified quantity of entities from table sorted by timestamp

Tags: sql, postgresql, pagination, sql-order-by, sql-limit

It's complicated but I will try to explain what do I mean. My idea is to server send to client next 50 records while user is scrolling a page. When user will arrive to specified in frontend point, fontend will ask server for next 50 entities. ***What SQL query do I need***? 
A query should work like (in pseudo-SQL): 
`SORT TABLE table_name SELECT entity BY INDEX (150-200)`.

I hope that I've explained understandable.

 Thanks so much ;)

EDIT 1
I'm using PostgreSQL.

Comment: This is called [tag:pagination]. Markus Winand wrote up some [good stuff on the topic](https://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2013-07/pagination-done-the-postgresql-way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer will depend on the SQL dialect that you are using. Below is a small example using T-SQL. It should point you in the right direction.
Here you should find an answer to your problem in T-SQL dialect:
[FETCH and OFFSET explained](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-offset-fetch/)

Edit:
For PostgreSQL check the following link:
[PostgreSQL FETCH example](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-fetch/)

```
SELECT
    product_name,
    list_price
FROM
    production.products
ORDER BY
    list_price,
    product_name 
OFFSET 10 ROWS 
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to check is it working. Im using PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the latest version of Postgres (13), then you can use a standard `fetch` clause:

```
select *
from mytable
order by id
offset 50 rows fetch next 50 rows only
```

Note that you do need a unique column (or set of column) in the `order by` clause to get a stable pagination. I assumed `id`.

In ealier version, where `fetch` is not available, one workaround uses window functions:

```
select *
from (select t.*, row_number() over(order by id) rn from mytable t) t
where rn between 51 and 100
```